# Docker compose container is not visible inside pgAdmin4

Tags: docker

I created a docker file to create a pgAdmin4 container and a postgres container.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 postgres:
   container_name: pg_container
   image: postgres
   restart: always
 environment:
   POSTGRES_USER: webquiver
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: webquiver
   POSTGRES_DB: quiver_db
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 pgadmin:
   container_name: pgadmin4_container
   image: dpage/pgadmin4
   restart: always
   environment:
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
   ports:
     - "5050:80"
```

When running docker compose up I can go to the localhost:5050 to reach pgAdmin4 and login in with my credentials you can see in the code.
But when I use the dropdown menu for servers, it is empty. nothing is created. And I can not create any server there. It does not allow me to. I get the Error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

please help. THX ^^

greetings

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your docker-compose file and everything is fine with it.
I'm guessing there is a misunderstanding how postgres and pgadmin are interacting with each other from scratch.
pgadmin is only the frontend that you can connect to a postgres database, it's not automatically searching for any existing postgres server.

I'm able to add the server inside the pgadmin with this host and port: postgres:5432 As inside the docker will resolve the service name as hostname `postgres` to the other service pgadmin.
[image]

This configuration will be lost, when the composition is restartet, as no volumes to persist the configuration are specified. Therefore, you have to follow steps from [Importing-servers](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_servers.html#importing-server) and repeat them every time you start the composition.
eg: build you own pgadmin image that specifies the json to import at startup

- Use the docker compose `build:`  [property](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) to specify a source

Comment: Thank you @fisehara for your answer. When creating an server I get the error I just added to my initial post

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a night of sleep I found the issue. For the server Host I wrote the db name and not the real container name. So pgAdmin could not find the container.

Have a nice day. : )